# CPP - strlen is not outputting entire length for multiple words [C-Strings Only]

Tags: c++

the code below is only outputting the length of the first word that I typed. I thought strlen would give me the length of multiple words, but it doesn't.

For example, the string "hello sir" gives me the output of 5 and not 8. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void ReadString(char * c, int maxLength);
void GetStringLength(char * c, int * length);

int main()
{

    int length = 0;
    const int SIZE = 20;
    char cpoint[SIZE];
    char *refC = cpoint;    

    ReadString(refC, SIZE);
    GetStringLength(refC, &length);
    system("pause");

}

void ReadString(char * c, int maxLength)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a string " << maxLength << " characters." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> c;

}

void GetStringLength(char * c, int * length)
{
    int sizeOfArray = std::strlen(c);
    *length = sizeOfArray;
    std::cout << sizeOfArray;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are not using `std::string` ?

Comment: Why all these C-strings? What's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: Please read more about `std::cin`.

Comment: `std::cin >> c;` stops at whitespace.  If you want to read a whole line use a function that does that, like getline.

Comment: just use std::string and std::getline

Comment: @RichardCritten It's for learning purposes.

Comment: Time to learn about `std::string` then.

Comment: @CroCo -- it's not `std::cin` that's the culprit; it's the stream extractor. You'd get the same behavior with any text stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he string "hello sir" gives me the output of 5 and not 8. Why is that?

You are using

```
std::cin >> c;
```

to read input into `c`. That will stop reading at the first whitespace. Hence, only `"hello"` is read into `c`, not `"hello sir"`.

If you want to read the entire line, you can use `std::string` for `c`, instead of `char*`, and then use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
getline(cin, c);
```

If you must use `char*`, I can think of the following options.

1. You can use [`istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

   ```
   cin.read(c, maxLength);
   ```

   and then, null-terminate `c`.

   ```
   c[cin.gcount()] = '\0';
   ```
2. You can use [`istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

   ```
   cin.getline(c, maxLength);
   ```

Comment: You failed to nul-terminate `c` if less than `maxLength` characters have been read. You're supposed to use [`gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) to know where to put the nul character.

Comment: Or you could use the istream getline member function http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: @NeilButterworth, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

The operator `>>` after `std::cin` only gives you the char array that can be found in `std::cin` until it hits whitespace, use `std::getline()` instead. This requires you to use `std::string` instead of a `char` array.

```
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
```

Also: `"Hello sir"` has a length of `9` and is an array with `10` elements.

Comment: It's not `std::cin`; it's the stream extractor (the `>>`). You'd get the same behavior with any text stream.